# Split column data for 2 new columns in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have column "position" in Mysql table1 that has data "N5241 E15601"

Im trying to split this in to 2 existing columns: lat and lon: "N5241" and "E15601"

I tried this code:

```
 INSERT INTO table1 (lat, lon)
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(Position, ' ', 1) AS lat,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Position, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) AS lon
FROM table1;
```

Above will add new rows, and will not update lat and lon column (Currently NULL)

I tried UPDATE, but I get errors.

I know this is easy for most of you, but Im still newbie...

Thanks
Hank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a simple UPDATE:

```
UPDATE table1
SET lat = SUBSTRING_INDEX(Position, ' ', 1),
    lon = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Position, ' ', 2), ' ', -1)
```

Note if your `Position` field is always `lat lon` with no extra spaces around it you can simplify that to

```
UPDATE table1
SET lat = SUBSTRING_INDEX(Position, ' ', 1),
    lon = SUBSTRING_INDEX(Position, ' ', -1)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=31d1a00b676fcb06a888b29fce47b135)

Comment: Perfecect. I'm using your second option, and it works just like I wanted. Simple.